# Commit Spring @Transactional before custom aspect invocation

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-aop

Method on service layer has 2 annotations. Spring `@Transactional` and my custom `@GenerateEmail`, which is join point to start `@AfterReturning` advice.

```
@Transactional
@GenerateEmail
public Long createEntity(CustomEntity entity){
    ...
}
```

And there is an advice:

```
@AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(generation)", returning = "id")
public void generateEmail(GenerateEmail generation, Long id) {
    processMailing(generation, id);
}
```

And there are some problems, cause by advices order invocations. Commit `@Transactional` is being call after mail generation.

First, I don't have access to uncommitted data. If I'm persisting `CustomEntity` with `@ManyToOne` field by its id, Hibernate will fetch the rest of the data only after committing transaction.

Second issue shows up when `generateEmail` throws `RuntimeException`. It's rollbacking `createEntity` transaction and I don't want this.

`@Order(2)` annotation on `generateEmail` is solving problem, but I'm not sure about it. It's seems not a good practice to hack advices order.

I can also move up my custom `@GenerateEmail` annotation to upper controller layer, where transaction is already committed, but I prefer to have it on service layer.

Can I commit transaction before `generateEmail` if it exists? Is it a good way to solve this? Or is it way to fix this in different way that I missed?

Comment: why don't you generate email asynchronously? so that it will not participate in current transaction and will not block normal execution?

Comment: Thats really good point. I will definitely try it.

Answer (score -1):

You could solve it like this:

```
@GenerateEmail
public Long createEntity(CustomEntity entity){
    doCreateEntity(entity);
}

@Transactional
private Long doCreateEntity(CustomEntity entity){
    ...
}
```

with both methods on service layer.
createEntity can be sure that the transaction is committed when executing @GenerateEmail.

Caution: this will only work when you use AOP for transactions, as private method calls will not be made transactional by the proxy.

Comment: Thanks, thats the way to solve this, but in future usage people will need to remeber it. I would prefer to not give responsibility for this on clients. Is it the only way?

Comment: Why? The client does not notice it; it calls createEntity like in your version. The interface of the service does not change.